# Passing a date in the Folder.GetTable("[SentOn] = date")

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to retrieve the email `SentOn` date from a mail item. However I am not sure how the syntax works when having a `Date` format that I would like to pass into the string. I tried "#" and "'" before and after the string and it still does not work. Here's my code:

```
Dim justDate As Date
Set objTable = Folder.GetTable("[SentOn]= *" & justDate & "*")
```

Comment: I think they have times on also, so 01/01/2018 00:00:00, so I think you need to do `>='01/01/2018 00:00:00' and <'02/01/2018 00:00:00'`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I need to pass my justDate variable, which is a timedate

Comment: Change it to a string then.

Comment: Can you show some more code?

Answer (score 0):

Never use "=" when working with dates - the comparison will always be false due to round-off errors. Always use a range ((SentOn > v1) and (SentOn < v2)).

Answer (score 0):

Although dates and times are typically stored with a Date format, the Outlook object model methods require that the date and time be converted to a string representation. To make sure that the date is formatted as Outlook expects, use the `Format` function. For example:

```
Sub DemoFindNext() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim tdystart As Date 
 Dim tdyend As Date 
 Dim myAppointments As Outlook.Items 
 Dim currentAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem 

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 tdystart = VBA.Format(Now, "Short Date") 
 tdyend = VBA.Format(Now + 1, "Short Date") 
 Set myAppointments = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items 
 Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.Find("[Start] >= """ &; tdystart &; 
 """ and [Start] <= """ &; tdyend &; """") 
 While TypeName(currentAppointment) <> "Nothing" 
  MsgBox currentAppointment.Subject 
  Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.FindNext 
 Wend 
End Sub
```